# If an annotation is associated with a method while declaring it in an interface, can we force the presence of annotation in the implementation class?

Tags: java, annotations

This is regarding use of annotations in Java. I associated an annotation with a method while declaring it in the interface. While implementing, how can I ensure that the annotation is carried along with @Override annotation and if not, it should throw a compilation error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

You need to write some code to do this (either on your applciation load time, or using [**apt**](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/GettingStarted.html))

I had the same scenario, and created an annotation of my own:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE)
public @interface DependsOn {
    Class<? extends Annotation>[] value();

    /**
     * Specifies whether all dependencies are required (default),
     * or any one of them suffices
     */
    boolean all() default true;
}
```

and applied it to other annotations, like:

```
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(value = ElementType.TYPE)
@DependsOn(value={Override.class})
public @interface CustomAnnotation {
}
```

Imporant: have in mind that `@Override` has a compile-time (`SOURCE`) retention policy, i.e. it isn't available at run-time.

Answer (score 2):

You can't enforce this in the compiler, no. It is the job of the tools which use those annotations to check all superclasses and interfaces when looking for annotations on a given class.

For example, Spring's `AnnotationsUtils` takes a class to examine for annotations, and crawls all over its inheritence tree looking for them, because the compiler and JVM does not do this for you.