# Forcing annotations in methods implementing abstract methods

Tags: java

How can I force method implementing abstract method to use defined set of annotations?
For example:

```
public abstract class Foo {
    @Test
    @OtherAnnotation()
    public abstract void doSomething(int a);
}

public class Bar extends Foo {
    @Override
    // Question: How to force programmer to place annotations here?
    public void doSomething(int a) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Thank You for answers and comments. To extend my question and separate it from other similar ones:

Would it be possible if it was testNG-related class?

Comment: Very closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056012/if-an-annotation-is-associated-with-a-method-while-declaring-it-in-an-interface

Comment: @Duncan Thanks for the link, I must have missed this one.

Answer (score 0):

**To put it simply, you can't**. Annotations, or 'comments' are not read by the compiler, and are purely for use by the programmer. This means that it is EXTREMELY hard - I would say impossible - to achieve this.